# Voltage Controlled Oscillator for An Arbitrary Sinusoid

Tags: matlab, frequency-modulation

[image]

I have a time-varying signal:

$$ y(t) = g(t) + a(t) \sin(2 \pi f_m t) $$

$g(t)$ and $a(t)$ are varying with time.. I have both of them as 2D arrays of [time value]

I need to perform VCO for $y(t)$ in MATLAB with these specifications:

$F_c$ = carrier center frequency = 560 Hz

$A_c$ = carrier amplitude = 10 V

$\Delta f$ = variation of oscillation frequency = $\pm$ 30 Hz

Any help how I can do it ?

Comment: what does the signal you have to do with the VCO you need to design? Also, we're not doing code written to your specification, so you'll have to explain what you've got so far, and the signal processing question that arose from that!

Comment: I changed "$f(t)$" to "$y(t)$" because you might need the former as a function of time denoting instantaneous frequency.